# How can I add a value in a column of previous row to a value in a column of the current row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Say I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Home Team | Away Team | Home Team Home Wins | Away Team Away Wins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BAR | MNU | 4 | 3 |
| RMD | BAR | 6 | 5 |
| MNU | CHE | 2 | 3 |
| CHE | RMD | 4 | 4 |

I want to add another column called Home Team Total Wins, with the following desired result:

| Home Team | Away Team | Home Team Total Wins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BAR | MNU | 4 |
| RMD | BAR | 6 |
| MNU | CHE | 5 |
| CHE | RMD | 7 |

The logic is that at each row, search backwards through the dataframe for the last row where Away Team equals Home Team for the current row. Then, take the Away Team Away Wins from that row and add it to the Home Team Home Wins of the current row. For example, in the third row we find the last row where Away Team == 'MNU', take its Away Team Away Wins value, and add it to the Home Team Home Wins value to create the new column (so we obtain 2+3 = 5).

I have attempted to do this with df.apply but have been unsuccessful thus far. Is there a way to do this in pandas, or do I need to go back to the drawing board and use a different data structure?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using mask and a `for` loop. This seems to be working as intended, but well, a solution without the `for` loop would be better!

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team':['BAR', 'RMD', 'MNU', 'CHE'],
                   'Away Team':['MNU', 'BAR', 'CHE', 'RMD'],
                   'Home Team Home Wins':[4, 6, 2, 4],
                   'Away Team Away Wins':[3, 5, 3, 4]})

df['Home Team Total Wins'] = None
for i in range(len(df)):
    home_team = df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Home Team')]
    idx_teams = [df.columns.get_loc('Home Team'), df.columns.get_loc('Away Team')]
    mask = df.iloc[:i+1, idx_teams].values == home_team
    idx_wins = [df.columns.get_loc('Home Team Home Wins'), df.columns.get_loc('Away Team Away Wins')]
    total_wins = df.iloc[:i+1, idx_wins].values[mask].sum()
    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Home Team Total Wins')] = total_wins

print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
|    | Home Team   | Away Team   |   Home Team Home Wins |   Away Team Away Wins |   Home Team Total Wins |
|----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------|
|  0 | BAR         | MNU         |                     4 |                     3 |                      4 |
|  1 | RMD         | BAR         |                     6 |                     5 |                      6 |
|  2 | MNU         | CHE         |                     2 |                     3 |                      5 |
|  3 | CHE         | RMD         |                     4 |                     4 |                      7 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, the data set I'm actually using this for is around 4000 rows so we'll see if a for loop can get the job done. Thanks anyways.